# Android Studio 3.2.1: transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED

Tags: android, android-studio-3.2

I want to migrate to Android Studio 3.2.1

I my project/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

In my app/build.gradle:

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 421
        versionName "2.1.421"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

// must be version 4.5.2
def AAVersion = '4.5.2'

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:ormlite:$AAVersion"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.1'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:ormlite-api:$AAVersion"

    implementation project(':binding')
    implementation project(':scanlib')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

But when build I get error:

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
, D:\dev\mobile\\My Project\android\FM\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\69.jar, D:\dev\mobile\\My Project\android\FM\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70.jar
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
107 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 100 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Clean and rebuild everything will work fine

Comment: Not help. I clean , invalidate cache and restart. But get same error.

Comment: Then it might faulty installation of any new thing on  Android Studio. Just reinstall it again

Comment: I reinstall Android Studio 3.2.1. But it not help. Maybe because I use any modules in my application?